# CSS Sprite: Unable to show a section of img from a collection of images

Tags: css, sprite

I am unable to get the section of the image I want from a collection of images. 
I generated this CSS from http://spritepad.wearekiss.com

```
.search_img1{
    background: url(/images/FBImages/1.png) no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.search_img1 {
    background-position: -152.98749923706055px 0;
}
```

The Img tag is :

```
<img id="search" src="images/FBImages/1.png" class="search_img1" title="search" alt="Seach" autocomplete="off">
```

[image: This is how the image appears while loading the page]

Comment: From where your are calling the image, as a background or foreground.

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake I was doing. I had mapped the background image twice. 
One at the time the img tag is desgined. and the other throughts its class [search_img1]